# Why does my meteor project refresh instead of reacting?

Tags: javascript, meteor, refresh, project

I have a few broken buttons in my meteor project. I have a feeling if one is fixed, all will be fixed, so here is the simplest one. The issue is that every time I press the update button, the browser refreshes instead of just changing data. I use a global variable so I can easily reuse data that I gather from a dropdown menu.

In my html:

```
  <template name="earning">
   <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form>
     <div class="form-group">

        <select class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="period">
 <option> Select a frequency.. </option>
        <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
        <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="earning"> Income:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="earning" id="earning" placeholder="Enter Income..." >


       </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Update </button>

     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </template>
```

And then in my js:

```
Template.earning.events({
"change #period": function(event, template) {
window.per = template.$("#period").val();
  console.log(window.per);
},
   "submit form": function(event, template) {
 var pearn = parseInt(event.target.earning.value);
 var period = window.per;
 console.log(income);
 if(period === 'monthly'){
   income = pearn*12;
 }
 else if(period === 'weekly'){
   income = pearn*52;
 }
 else
   income = period;


 console.log(income);
 inc = {Period: period, Income: pearn};  }});
```

Do I need helpers for my

Comment: The default action on the submit button is likely not suppressed.

Comment: Thank you! How exactly do I do this?

Comment: Well, easiest method would be to remove `type="submit"` (which removes the default action) - it will still be a clickable button, and client-side events will still work. I don't know how meteor works, though and this might break the "submit form" stuff. YMMV.

Comment: Many thanks. This helps a lot